# Trying to switch to linux as a PHP developer, can't move my development environment

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, xampp

I'm using Windows for my development operations but i'm deploying to Debian/Ubuntu based distros. So i thought if i move my development to a linux distro it will be more comfortable.

I'm using XAMPP on windows for apache/mysql servers. It's on my portable hard drive. So, if i'm at home i just open XAMPP control panel and click Start Apache, Start Mysql. It works "drive-letter free". So if my portable hard disk is on D drive on my laptop, my document-root is "/www" regardless of drive letter. XAMPP thinks "well, /www is on the root of the drive which i'm running". And after that, if i go to work and plug-in my hard drive (say, it's G) XAMPP can still work because it search for folder relative to drive root.

So my question is: How can i setup a development environment as easy as the example given above?

Dropbox, Git and cp, mv are not viavle options by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you (1) simulate the linux path on Windows, or (2) use symlinks to the correct locations on linux?

Comment: I cant understand what you are asking in 1 but i can answer 2: Sure i can symlink /var/www to /media/usb_disk/www but if i install apache2 with "apt-get install apache2" i think it works under "www-data" user but the usb disk is formatted with NTFS and there is no linux style permission mechanism.

Comment: What level of security do you need in your dev environment?  You can mount the usb stick with full access to all local users, which would let apache access the files

Comment: i dont need any security but can i show a folder on my usb disk as document-root to apache? and when my usb disk is not plugged-in when i switch on the computer apache will tell thar the folder is inaccessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to configure your linux-apache to have an empty folder as document root. Then you plug in your usb stick as usual, and it gets automounted. With mount you can now override the empty folder with the subfolder of your mounted usbstick:

```
sudo mount -o bind /media/usbstick/.../document_root /var/www
```

You can probably also add this somewhere to some automount scripts, but this would be another question.

Comment: This is OK for apache but i also run MySQL as a portable program too. How can i do this in ubuntu? (sync dbs with usb drive)

Comment: You can do it the same way, as long as you don't have any local DB content. mount totally hides the former content of the target folder. Or you simply run mysqld with the --basedir option.